NuGet package validation during build
I'm trying to build .NET core 8 application with option DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION set to true. I'm building in OpenShift S2I and using private NuGet repo (Artifactory).
If DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=true build takes about 3,5 hours.
If DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false build takes about 3 minutes.
I found article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/the-nuget-org-repository-signing-certificate-will-be-updated-as-soon-as-april-8th-2024/ mentioning that I need to set-up finger print to trusted signer, which I did, but it did not help. In build logs I can see warnings NU3018 and errors NU3034.
NU3018 The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server could not be reached. RevocationStatusUnknown: unable to get certificate CRL
NU3034 This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.

Waringn leads me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/nuget-signed-package-verification where is mentioned, that cenrtification bundle is searched at location
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/objsign-ca-bundle.pem

I guess I need to add it there, but where I can get it?
I'm not a developer. I'm trying to set OpenShift for our dev guys.
What should I do with NU3034. Do I need some nuget.config vaules from developers?
Thank you.

This github issue should help you understand why signature verification is taking a long time when network requests are blocked: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13659#issuecomment-2297796060

nuget.config settings are expected to commit into the source control repository, not set up on the CI agent, so the devs should be able to change that themselves. Here are the docs on trusted signers, which when used, requires all packages to be signed by those trusted signers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#trustedsigners-section

Thank you Zivkan. Firstly I had wrong configuration in nuget.config. I set nuget.org as trusted repository. (the purpose of nuget.config being in configured build pipeline is to control which packages are allowed and which not)
Next I set NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE = offline. I still get warings about revocation function cannot check revocation, but at least I'm able to verifiy, that packges was signed. It is not ideal, I'm trying to set it up properly.
